# The best way to run a script inside Python

Tags: python

I would like to call a script inside Python.
I tried os.system but I'm afraid it's not the best option.

Python version 2.3.4

I have the code below:

```
runScript = (start + ' ' + middle + filename + ' > ' + final + urlFinal + '.log')
os.system(runScript)
```

start = /xxxx/xxx/xxxx/_mfgadd.bash

middle, filename, final and urlfinal are arguments for .bash.

Well, when I just tried:

```
print runScript
```

It works perfectly. 
So, what is the best way to execute "runScript"?

Thanks

Comment: The recommended way according to the manual of the standard python library is the use of the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem doing it your way really, however as Serge mentioned the Subprocess module is more typical:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['./example.sh'])
```

Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Subprocess is for 2.4 above and my Python version is 2.3.4. Yeah, i know it is old but I can't update it now.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: @user2287892 In that case i'd use os.system as well. Perhaps mention your python version in the question.